# Azure IoT Central - Query for device group failing on creation

Tags: azure, api, azure-iot-central

I'm trying to create device groups to eventually create a Job with this particular device group to send a reboot command to all the devices in it. I'm using the IoT Central API REST for this with the URL looking like this (which is how it is on their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/2022-07-31dataplane/device-groups/create?tabs=HTTP)): `PUT https://{subdomain}.{baseDomain}/api/deviceGroups/{uuidCreatedByMe}?api-version=2022-07-31`

The body on the request looks something like this:

```
{
    description: `Pulses' group to be rebooted, created at ${DateTime.now().toISO()}`,
    displayName: `Reboot group ${deviceGroupId}`,
    filter: query,
}
```

And the query is very similar to this

```
SELECT * FROM devices WHERE $template = "templateId" AND $id IN ["deviceId1", "deviceId2"]
```

But for some reason, when I send the request, it responds with an error:

```
Request failed with status 500 and error: {
   "code": "InternalServerError",
   "message": "Something went wrong on our end. Please try again. You can contact support at https://aka.ms/iotcentral-support. Please include the following information. Request ID: requestId, Time: Tue, 06 Sep 2015 477:10:01 GMT.",
   "requestId": "requestId",
   "time": "Tue, 06 Sep 2022 16:10:01 GMT"
}
```

However, when I try to create a Job and get the list of device groups, this brings me all the device groups I have been attempting to create, but it doesn't let me see the number of devices and doesn't allow me to continue creating the Job. And then, I request through the REST API to delete such device group with one of the ids, and it deletes it just fine.

My question would be...

Is this related to the query or what exactly?...

Because [according to their documentation this is a valid query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-query-with-rest-api#value-comparisons)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that it is not supported yet, try to use `($id= '' OR $id = '')` to work around now.

Comment: It doesn't work like that, either. The response that I get says, ` The provided filter is not valid. A device group filter can only reference properties and cannot contain nested conditions`. No luck here

Comment: @EliasRodelo, you are right, this is not supported, I double checked this from UX, seems user only be able to do one way filter with 'AND' logic operator, OR is not supported in this case, reported this to our PM as feature request.